# Automating login page test cases using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As I am new to Selenium and Java I got stuck while testing a login page. Below is my code which I am trying to test to always it is returning `Test case failed` even if I am giving the correct username and password. I wondering where it is going wrong. URL is also correct while checking the equal condition. The URL I have taken post login into the site.

```
package Seleniumtesting;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); 
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.get("https://onelogin.adityabirlacapital.com/login");
    d.findElement(By.id("login-id")).sendKeys("my_username");
    d.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("my_password");
    //d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password-login\"]")).click();
    d.findElement(By.id("password-login")).click();
    String u = d.getCurrentUrl();
    if(u.equalsIgnoreCase("https://onelogin.adityabirlacapital.com/my-dashboard"))
    {
        System.out.println("Test case passed");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Test case failed");
    }
        d.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try printing the value held in variable `u` and see where the difference is?

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh In the variable ```u``` I am getting ```https://onelogin.adityabirlacapital.com/login``` URL but why it is not fetching the exact URL post login that matches with the expected URL and print as ```Test case passed```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding delay before executing `d.getCurrentUrl()`. Something like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);` into your code to make sure that everything is loaded retrieving the value of the current URL after clicking login.

Other solution might be, after clicking login button via Selenium, find any element in the homepage that possibly indicates a user is successfully logged in, such as welcome messages or if there's already a logout button.